# Regex to match if given text is not found and match as little as possible

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have text:

```
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>BBzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
```

I can't parse it as xml. I need to use regex here. Also this is only example.

I want regex that can match every group `<a>...</a>` that does not contain element `b` with text that starts with `BB`.

I came up with this regex:
`<a>.*?<b>(?!B).*?</b>.*?</a>`
But it matches last group as:

```
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>BBzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
```

Which is bad for me.

**How to write regex that will only match those 3 group from my given example?**:

**1.**

```
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
```

**2.**

```
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
```

**3.**

```
<a>
sdfsdf
<b>DDzz</b>
sdfsdf
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) regex:

```
<a>(?:(?!<(?:b>BB|/?a>)).)*</a>
```

Enable the *`.` matches newline* option.

**Details**:

- `<a>`  - a literal `<a>` char sequence
- `(?:(?!<(?:b>BB|/?a>)).)*` - a tempered greedy token matching any char (`.`) that is not the starting symbol of  a sequence that can be matched with the pattern inside the `(?!<(?:b>BB|/?a>))` lookahead (not a `<b>BB` or `</a>` or `<a>` sequence)
- `</a>`  - a literal `</a>` char sequence

[image]